# Find f:R->R such that f(U) is open for all open sets U, but f is not continuous.

Tags: general-topology

The title says it all, really. I'm confronted with this problem from my topology course, and I have made no progress. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to solve it with the "standard" topology on R or something else, but I think its true even with the "standard" topology- I just can't find such a function.

I would add that this is an introductory course in topology and I don't know most advanced notions.

Comment: Try with $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x):=1/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: if I take the open interval ]-0.5,0.5[, the image would give me {1}U]-infinity,-2[U]2,infinity[, no? And this isn't open...